# Error when using mutate and case_when with Error in charToDate(x)

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr

I am trying to use case when and mutate to modify an existing column in my database. 
Example:

id: `c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...)`

Type: `c('x', 'y', 'unknown')` - 3 levels

Date_of_regsitering `(2011-06-03, NA, NA, 2017-05-02, NA, NA, 2012-05-02...)`

Only some of the observations have this date.

Date_of_enrollment `(NA, NA, 2015-04-03, NA, 2012-08-02, 2010-05-01...)`

Only some of the observations have this date.

I want to change any 'unknown' in the 'Type' column, based if there is a 'Date of registering' or 'Date of enrollment', in other words as longs as the Date columns have a date in them and are not NA then to change one of the 'unknown's in the Type column to either x or y:

I've constructed the following code in R studio:

```
Df <- Df %>%
    mutate(Type = case_when(Type='unknown'& Date_of_registering !='NA'~'x',
                            Type='unknown'& Date_of_enrollment!='NA' ~ 'y',
                            TRUE ~ Type))
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: n.b. `NA` is not a string in R. Instead of `Date_of_registering !='NA'` you should use `!is.na(Date_of_registering)`

Comment: Note that for testing for equality you need `==` (two equals signs), not one (`=`).  Like `Type == "unknown" & !is.na(Date_of_registering)`

Comment: It also looks like your error you are quoting is earlier in your code when trying to parse the dates. Could you share that?

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped! The full error that was coming to answer your comment @Jamie was: Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues here which is that the evaluation should be done with two equal signs instead of one, and that in identifying whether column is NA or not it is better to use is.na(x).

The following code should solve the problem.

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Type <- c('x', 'y', 'unknown', 'x', 'y', 'unknown', 'x', 'unknown')
Date_of_registering <- as.Date(c("2011-06-03", NA, "2017-05-02", NA, NA, NA, "2012-05-02", NA))
Date_of_enrollment <- as.Date(c(NA, NA, "2015-04-03", NA, "2012-08-02", "2010-05-01", NA, NA))

Df <-
  data.frame(id, Type, Date_of_registering, Date_of_enrollment, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(new_type = 
           case_when(Type == 'unknown' & !is.na(Date_of_registering) ~ 'x',
                     Type == 'unknown' & !is.na(Date_of_enrollment) ~ 'y',
                     TRUE ~ Type))
```